# get serializearray() elements with ajax and node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax

I would like to get input elements from my form to node js:

Client Side

```
var ss =( $('#addform').serializeArray() );
var url= 'http://localhost:8181/add';
    $.ajax({
        url:url,
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: "json",
        data:{ss:ss},
        success: function(json){
            alert("done");          
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, err) {
        alert('text status '+textStatus+', err '+err)
    }
});
```

[Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object]

Server Side:

```
router.route('/adduser')
.post(function(req, res) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
      console.log(req.body);
      console.log(req.body.name);
}
```

Result:

```
{ ss: 
   [ { name: 'name', value: 'a' },
     { name: 'lastname', value: 'a' },
     { name: 'email', value: 'a' },
     { name: 'password', value: 'a' },
     { name: 'password2', value: 'a' },
     { name: 'country', value: 'a' },
     { name: 'phone', value: 'a' } ] }
```

`console.log(req.body.name);` returns undefined

How can I get elements of these objects in server side ?

Comment: Try to pass data using JSON.Stringify()

Comment: @geminiousgoel — How could that possibly help?

Comment: Server will get what you pass and if it will receive groom data it will use otherwise i can't get data from object!

Comment: @geminiousgoel I already pass with JSON.Stringify() in the client side

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SS variable is an array of objects. So you have to iterate over the object with loops.

```
var data = req.body.ss;
    for(var i in data){
          console.log(data[i].name);
    }
```

Comment: It return undefined

Comment: i have changed code. i was forgot to mention ss from req.body. This should work.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> req.body.name
> ```

This is not surprising.

**Look** at `req.body` (you're already logging it and you quoted it in the question!).

The only property the object has is `ss`, the value of which is an array. It doesn't have a `name` property.

---

Don't do this:

> ```
> var ss =( $('#addform').serializeArray() );
> ```

It doesn't give you the data in the format you want.

Use [`serialize`](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/) instead.

```
var ss = $('#addform').serialize();
```

That will give you a URL encoded string. So pass that directly to data instead of passing an object:

```
data: ss,
```

Comment: This is the result in the console.log(ss) in (browser) name=a&lastname=a&email=a&password=a&password2=a&country=a&phone=a

and in the server:
{ ss: 'name=a&lastname=a&email=a&password=a&password2=a&country=a&phone=a'}

How can i get the value of name ?

Comment: @ahmed — The first is expected. The second sounds like you ignored the last paragraph and last line of code in this answer.